# Closing multiple windows with CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, windows-xp, taskkill

I have been working on a batch-file program that opens multiple windows and then closes them all at the same time. I can use the TASKKILL command on Windows 10 to close them all simultaneously. I also want to use the program on Windows XP Home SP3 but it doesn't have the TASKKILL command. So my overall question is: Is there any way to close multiple windows on Windows XP through the Command Prompt without any 3rd party software? Also, here is the batch code I am using:

```
@echo off
:init
cls
color 0f
title Test A1
start %RandomProgram%
ping localhost -n 10 >nul
start %RandomProgram%
ping localhost -n 10 >nul
start %RandomProgram%
ping localhost -n 10 >nul
start %RandomProgram%
ping localhost -n 10 >nul
start %RandomProgram%
ping localhost -n 15 >nul
::Close all the above windows here::
```

Comment: Windows XP has [TSKILL](https://ss64.com/nt/tskill.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! You can post it as an answer so I can mark the post as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) was right,

> Windows XP has [TSKILL](https://ss64.com/nt/tskill.html)